# redis-cli: Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--tls'

Tags: redis

I'm trying to start a redis server with the support for tls. Based on the documentation (https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) I execute this command:

`redis-cli -a xxxxxxxxx --tls --cacert ../config/certs/test-ca.crt`

But it return this error:

> Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--tls'

My redis-cli version is 6.0.9

I can't figure out what am I missing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you performed make of the redis, you should run as:
make BUILD_TLS=yes

Comment: I used brew to install redis on osx and had version 5 installed. brew upgrade redis upgraded to 6.0.1 with TLS support included

Comment: If one gets `fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory`. Run: `sudo apt install openssl libssl-dev`

Comment: can anyone please guide on how to connect from windows machine, I am also facing similar error ?

Answer (score 8):

Install dependencies

## update package information from repo

```
sudo apt update
```

## install build dependencies

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential pkg-config libssl-dev tcl libjemalloc-dev wget
Download and extract the redis-cli source file
```

## download the package

```
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
```

## extract the package

```
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
```

## go inside the extracted directory

```
cd redis-stable
```

Build with tls enabled

## remove previously generated build files

```
make distclean
```

## build with tls option

```
make BUILD_TLS=yes
Once completed you can validate the build and connect to Redis-server
```

## validate the redis-cli

```
Redis-CLI -h localhost -p 6379 --tls
```

localhost:6379> INFO SSL

## SSL

```
ssl_enabled:yes
ssl_current_certificate_not_before_date:Jul 27 00:00:00 2021 GMT
ssl_current_certificate_not_after_date:Aug 25 23:59:59 2022 GMT
ssl_current_certificate_serial:ABCDEFGKKSHDJKAHSD05A15BF008A57002E8
```